# Why JS if() function not executing in safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have this code, which displays or hides text blocks according to the button pressed. The menu is from two buttons, and when one button is pressed it triggers the text to be displayed and hides another text.
The code works fine on chrome, but on safari, only the first piece of code works (the one which adds a new class to the button). What could be an issue here?

I tried to test by printing the button text (just before `alert("The browser shows this alert");`) and the code prints button text correctly. But I can't get into the if().

```
$(".about-us-button1").on('click', function () {
  $(".about-us-button1").removeClass('active');

  var button = $(this);

  $(this).addClass('active');

  for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
    var name = button[i].innerText;
    alert("The browser shows this alert");
    if (name === 'Cargo booking form' || name === 'Krovinių užsakymo forma' || name === 'ЗАКАЗ') {
      alert('The browser not reaching this piece of code');
      $(".cargo-booking").addClass('visible');
      $(".request-cargo").removeClass('visible');
      
    }
    if (name === "Request about cargo" || name === "Užklausa apie krovinį" || name === "Запрос Стоимости") {
      $(".cargo-booking").removeClass('visible');
      $(".request-cargo").addClass('visible');
      alert('The browser not reaching this piece of code');
    }
  }
});
```

After running the command `console.log(escape(name))` I got a different results at Chrome: `Request%20about%20cargo` and Safari: `<h2>Request about cargo</h2>`

I can't find a simple way to get a text from an HTML object, that works on all browsers.

Comment: Check for any javascript errors, that would interrupt execution. You probably didn't meet the if requirements. Log the value you see on `name`.

Comment: Check that both your JavaScript and your HTML are being sent with the `charset` part of [`Content-Type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) and that they match. I suspect some of those characters may be getting mangled.

Comment: Probably whitespace or hidden characters. `console.log(escape(name))`

Comment: Your best bet here is to debug this. Sadly, Apple makes that hard if you're not on a Mac. :-| But you can still resort to the horrible `alert` to at least see what value the code thinks `name` has when you click the button that should match one of those names but doesn't.

Comment: The name value is the same as in the string, I tested it. The code works on the Chrome browser!!!? Lithuanian and Russian charset are included in the UTC-8. Anyway, if in the if() method I leave the button name only in English it still now works. No errors in the console

Answer (score 1):

try to change
var name = button[i].innerText;

to this:
var name = button[i].textContent;

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my Safari issue too.